# Pullbacks and Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hi guy I am given two varieties $V(x_1^4+x_2^4-1)$ and $V(y_1^2+y_2^2-1)$ and I have the morphism $\phi(a_1,a_2)=(a_1^2,a_2^2)$
We want to show that $\phi (V(x_1^4+x_2^4-1)) \subset V(y_1^2+y_2^2-1)$

My approach was let $a \in \phi (V(x_1^4+x_2^4-1))$ which means $a=(a_1^2,a_2^2)$ and we know that $a_1^4+a_2^4-1=0$ so when we check if a is in $V(y_1^2+y_2^2-1)$ we see that $(a_1^2)^2-(a_2^2)^2-1=0$.
I thought it was quite easy, but we have a hint to use the pull back and the lemma:
If $\phi (V) \subset W$ iff $\phi^*I(W) \subset I(V)$ where $\phi^*= g (\phi)$ is the standard pullback

Comment: You have, more or less, proved one direction of the lemma in a special case.

Comment: Would you say my proof is aceptable